# Text Wrapping inside a grid

Tags: wpf

I have a grid which has seven columns. In each one of these columns there is another grid, and the inner grid has three rows. The middle row contains a list box which again has a grid inside a data template. The inner most grid has two columns in the first column I am binding a name and in the second one I am binding a number. A text block is used in both the cases, there is no text wrapping taking place in the Name column even when the text wrapping has been set to wrap, the widths of all the columns are set to "`*`" , the height of the list box is "`*`", the horizontal and vertical alignment of almost all the elements are stretch.

Any suggestions???

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't defined any specific width for your grid columns, the text won't write (default value is Auto, so the column will increase according to the textblock width)

I'd suggest you specify a fixed width to the columns(and I'd encourage you to use * and not finite pixels )